# How to construct a .vtk file with point data from numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I want to build a .vtk file that contains point positions and associated data (e.g. pressure, velocity vector).

So far I have tried the vtk poly data writer like so :

```
polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()
vtk_points = vtk.vtkPoints()

for i in range(0, positions.shape[0]):
    vtk_points.InsertNextPoint(positions[i, 0], positions[i, 1], positions[i,2])

polydata.SetPoints(vtk_points)
    
writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName(filename)
writer.SetInputData(polydata)

writer.Update()
```

This works. However, in Paraview I can only see the point when I select 'Point Gaussian'.
Also, I cannot add any data to those points and can not find a fitting example.

As mentioned the data I want to add are scalars (pressure) and vectors (velocity in all directions).

How can I proceed?

Comment: I think you are looking for "How to set arrays in polydata". You can set your "pressure", "velocity" etc as separate arrays.

Comment: Also VTK/ParaView only display cells in 3d views. To see points in other mode than `Point Gaussian` you should add cells in your polydata. Some [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/PolyData/ColoredTriangle/) about polydata and [doc](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/vtkNumPyIntegration.html) to use VTK with numpy

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use the dataset adapters from `vtk.numpy_interface`

```
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import algorithms as algs
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
import numpy as np


xs, ys, zs = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), np.arange(10))

vectors = np.random.random((10, 10, 10, 3)).astype(np.float32)

polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()

pts = vtk.vtkPoints()
points = algs.make_vector(xs.ravel(),
                          ys.ravel(),
                          zs.ravel())
pts.SetData(dsa.numpyTovtkDataArray(points, "Points"))

polydata.SetPoints(pts)

vectors = algs.make_vector(vectors[:,:,:,0].ravel(),
                           vectors[:,:,:,1].ravel(),
                           vectors[:,:,:,2].ravel())
polydata.GetPointData().SetScalars(dsa.numpyTovtkDataArray(vectors, "Velocity"))
```